# JavaScript basic replace two chars in same string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have:

```
var foo = '(bar)'
foo.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
```

So, I get `bar` without parentheses, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
foo = foo.replace(/[()]/g, '');
```

That involves a simple regular expression that matches all instances of either open- or close-parentheses.
Note that you have to include that assignment, as ".replace()" does not *modify* the string; it *returns* the modified string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex capturing everything inside parentheses in a capturing group as per [Javascrip Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) e.g.

```
var foo = "(bar)";
var replacedStr = foo.replace(/\((.*)\)/g, "$1");
```

or replacing just the parentheses with empty string e.g.

```
var foo = "(bar)";
var replacedStr = foo.replace(/[()]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the first and last characters you are trying to get rid of, you could use the slice method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

```
​var foo = '(bar)';
alert(foo.slice(​​​​​​​​1, 4));
//Or
alert(foo.slice(1, foo.length - 1));​
```